# Angular last '/' route to proper URL

Tags: angularjs

I want to route with last '/' or without last '/' to proper URL . Here is test code.

```
function configSignupLandingState ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('test', {
        url: '/test',
        templateUrl: '/states/test/test.html',
        controller: 'signupLandingController as vm',
        requiredAuthentication: {
            loggedOut: true
        }
    });
}
```

Now assume url is '/test/' or '/test' both should go to test.html.
But for above function only '/test' is working fine.
Any idea how can i achieve both cases ?

Comment: then where is this `'/test/'` going? have you defined `otherwise` in the config?

Comment: Yes it's defined it's redirect to Home page.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at this article:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes